# Website vertical scrollbar issue persists on lower resolution screen 1360x768

Tags: html, vertical-scrolling

I've been trying to solve this for a while, may be a simple issue for those of you who's seen this  issue.

Website: http://www.feisworld.com/

Issue: vertical scroll-bar on the left hand-side where the nav is.

WordPress theme: MOKA, a fairly clean template

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

Your scrollbar only appears when the "Work with fei" message comes on top of the page. On closing that message, the scrollbar is removed. I would advise you to display that message on a modal window instead of what it is at present.

Regards. Hope your problem can be solved by this.

Comment: I tried disabling the Work With Fei header but the issue persists. Thanks for your comment.